# How can I find, is any wifi router connected in my network

Tags: macos, networking, monitoring, snmp

I am trying to develop an application for network monitoring. A part of this application is to detect "is any wifi router connected to any switches ports".
Basically, I have a mysql database table where I have all the mac addresses of devices(pc,wifi router,..) connected to each switch port(by SNMP). As far I know, first three bytes of mac address (Organizationally Unique Identifier - OUI) represent the vendor/manufacturer of the device. So, I want to make a list of all known vendors who manufacture wifi routers (Linksys,TP-LINK,Netgear,SMC,..) and make a match with the OUI to the mac addresses stored in database.

Q1. Is the solution correct? or what would be the appropriate way to solve this problem.

It would be a great help if any one suggest me what should be the appropriate way.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not an appropriate solution. For example, macOS allows a Macintosh to act as a Wi-Fi router via the [Internet Sharing](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25327) feature, but its Ethernet MAC address will still just have a regular Apple vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Gordon Davisson you will be missing "Internet sharing"-constructions, so your results will be incomplete (i.e. False Negatives).

Another source of False Negatives could be wireless routers using NICs from a large generic vendor (think Intel).

Besides that; the OUI will tell you what the device's vendor is, but NOT what kind of device it is. It could, for instance, be a WIRED router, leading to results which are not, in fact, wireless routers (i.e. False Positives).

The big pain in the behind for your problem is that what you are trying to detect; a (wireless) router; shields certain data-traffic from clients behind from means of identification that would aid you in your query.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no appropriate solution for this.

Comment: Not one that is 100% (or even 90+%) accurate, no.